# DOM append child of a text node not working

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to insert a text node into an  tag in my document, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work (I don't get any messages, just doesn't work!). HTML and JS below. Any help will be very appreciated!

**HTML (only the part that matters):**

```
<div>
    <h4 id="hompageNameDiv"></h4>
</div>
```

**Java Script (again, only the part we actually care about):**

```
window.onload = function () {
 var userPersonalName = "jonathan";
 var didSetPersonalname = true;
 if (didSetPersonalName == true) {
  var nametextNode = document.createTextNode(userPersonalName);
  var hompageUserPersonalName = document.getElementById("hompageNameDiv");
  hompageUserPersonalname.appendChild(nametextNode);

 }
}
```

**Again, ANY help is highly appreciated! :D**

Comment: *"I don't get any messages"*, I do: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: didSetPersonalName is not defined"* (see http://jsfiddle.net/956NC/). Once you fixed this, you will get *"Uncaught ReferenceError: hompageUserPersonalname is not defined"* and when you fixed that it works. JavaScript is case-sensitive, `name` is not the same as `Name`.

Comment: cheers :) God do I hate case sensitivity!? Such a pain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two typos:

- `didSetPersonalname` vs `didSetPersonalName`
- `hompageUserPersonalName` vs `hompageUserPersonalname`

Variable names in JS are case sensitive. Also, learn how to use your browser's debugging facility ;-) nowadays, nearly all browsers have it:

- Firefox (Firebug)
- IE9+ (press F12)
- Chrome

Comment: wat about OS X Safari? any built in solutions within dreamwever?

Comment: Even Safari on the phone has a debug console :)

Answer (score 0):

Your variables names are different ... watch out that naming in JavaScript is case sensitive.